# Using Disk and Memory Cache for gallery

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap

I am trying to create a gallery in my app following general guidelines on Google's website. I have the gallery working using `AsyncTask` (code posted below).

However, there are two problems:

1) The images re-load one-by-one every time I leave and return to the gallery activity. The gallery is contained in a fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)`.

2) The images do not load very quickly and sometimes it can lag (for instance, if I swipe through the `ViewPager` too fast in the detail view).

To fix this, I think I have to implement the `LruCache` and `DiskCache` segments of the tutorial, [seen here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#memory-cache). But I'm not sure how to do this while maintaining the code I've already written below. Google's tutorials seem to overlap- for example, the method `loadBitmap` is different during the cache tutorials, and I'm not sure how to merge that with what I have below.

Note: These images are saved to internal storage- I'm not downloading them.

Can anyone give me advice/examples of how to implement an `LruCache` and `DiskCache` into the below code? I'm very new to these parts of Android and it can get confusing. Thank you!

`GalleryAdapter.java`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    View v = view;
    ImageView imageView;

    if (v == null)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.image, v.findViewById(R.id.image));
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.image);

    loadBitmap(position, imageView);

    return v;
}

public void loadBitmap(int data, ImageView imageView)
{
    if (cancelPotentialWork(data, imageView))
    {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(data);
    }
}

static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable
{
    private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask)
    {
        super(res, bitmap);
        bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask()
    {
        return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }
}

public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView)
{
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null)
    {
        final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
        if (bitmapData == 0 || bitmapData != data)
        {
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView)
{
    if (imageView != null)
    {
        final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable)
        {
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
            return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        data = params[0];
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPaths.get(data)), 100, 100, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {

        if (isCancelled())
        {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null)
        {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `setRetainInstance` only helps you when the activity is being destroyed and re-created due to orientation change. It does not help you with the ViewPager. For that, try using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: @GregEnnis Thanks for the tip. Actually I meant `setRetainInstance` is on the main gallery view where all the images are displayed together. The `ViewPager` does extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I thought `setRetainInstance` might prevent all the images from being re-loaded every time I navigate back to the gallery fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The ViewPager is very difficult to get right (beyond simple demos) and async loading/caching images is also tricky. Not a fun project for " very new to these parts". You might want to use a 3rd party image library that helps a lot with this. For example, Picasso or Universal Image Loader, both popular for this.

Comment: I'll look into Picasso and UIL and see if I can implement them! Everything and the ViewPager above does work, it's just not optimal though. I agree, definitely tricky getting everything to work right.